# driver.get("https://www.python.org") not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to learn Selenium with python. 
So trying to access a website but it is not working

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome")

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://www.python.org/")
```

Error in Console:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.7 /Users/adeshpande/PycharmProjects/Selenium/Tests/LoginPagesTest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adeshpande/PycharmProjects/Selenium/Tests/LoginPagesTest.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are passing the path to the Chrome Browser in your call `webdriver.Chrome`.
You should be passing the path to `ChromeDriver` which is a separate program. You can download it from https://chromedriver.chromium.org

After downloading and installing it, pass the path to where you installed it and you should be good to go!